# How to clear multiple Edit text values?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an app. in the Main activity i have an options menu with 2 items.
one of the items is called "Clear".
I have 5 edit texts,1 spinner and 4 radio buttons.
i want to make that item to clear all the information entered into edit text and radio button and spinner.
how can i do that?

Comment: I figured out the code for item in options menu.
First you should create a method and then for each edit text put this code inside that method.
EditText firsttxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ftxt);
        firsttxt.setText("");
then call the method.

Answer (score 2):

You'd do it the same way you clear a single edit text, but five times. Since you didn't bother to include your code, I'll have to make some assumptions about how you've named things, but the following should be clear enough:

```
Button buttonClear = findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
    buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
            editText4.setText("");
            editText5.setText("");
        }
    });
```